# Solve Riccati equaiton $x'(t) + x^2(t) = \sin(t) + \cos(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given differential equation is $$x'(t) + x^2(t) = \sin(t) + \cos(t)$$ I was able to notice that this is a Riccati equation, but could not actually solve, since I do not know none of its partial solutions.

Comment: Start by taking $x(t) = y'(t)/y(t)$ and obtain a second order linear ODE for $y$.

Comment: You can always use the standard method to transform this into a linear second order problem. Set $x=\frac{u'}{u}$ to get $u''-(\sin t+\cos t)u=0$. This is a Hill's equation

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac{\dot u}{u}.$ Then,
$$
\dot x=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\dot u}{u}=\frac{u\ddot u-\dot u^2}{u^2},\\
x^2=\frac{\dot u^2}{u^2}.
$$
So the DE becomes 
$$
\ddot u=u(\sin t+\cos t)=\sqrt2u\cos(t-\frac{\pi}{4}).
$$
Let $2x=t-\frac{\pi}{4},2dx=dt.$ Let $y(x)=u(t)=u(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}).$
$$\frac{1}{4}y''=\sqrt2 y\cos(2x).
$$
This is a [Mathieu Differential Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuDifferentialEquation.html).
$$
y''-4\sqrt2 y\cos2x=0
$$
So $a=0,q=2\sqrt 2$.(See picture)

The general solution is 
$$
y=AC(0,2\sqrt2,x)+BS(0,2\sqrt2,x),
$$
Where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants and $C,S$ are Mathieu Functions.
Now substitute back.
[image: Mathieu Differential Equation]

Comment: $u’’=e^{-ix}u$. Has a closed form solution. And then you take the imaginary part.

Comment: @player100 Your approach seems interesting. Could you write another answer so I can understand what you mean?

Comment: I would upvote this except for the giant image at the end

Comment: @player100 That doesn't work. For that to work $u$ would have to be real, but that ODE has no non-trivial solutions for which $u$ is real.

Comment: You are right @Winther. That comment wasnt well thought out